# How to push a widget outside of context?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

My current screenstructure looks like this:

```
Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            _buildOffstageNavigator(FeedScreen()),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(Screen2()),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(Screen3()),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
      )
```

the BottomNavigationBar is just a regular bar.

Each of those screens are wrapped with a OffStage() widget like this:

```
 Widget _buildOffstageNavigator(Widget screenToBuild) {
    return Offstage(
      offstage: currentPage != screenToBuild,
      child: TabNavigator(
        navigatorKey: _navigatorKeys[screenToBuild],
        screenToBuild: screenToBuild,
      ),
    );
  }
```

My intention with this was to ensure a BottomNavigationBar at all times.

However, there is one widget, that I want to push from `FeedScreen()` that I don't want the `NavigationBar` on, but the context makes it hard to hide this `NavigationBar`

This is the structure of the `FeedScreen()`

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        key: PageStorageKey<String>("Feed"),
        controller: _feedSC,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildStoriesListView(),
            buildPostsListView(posts)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

So my question is: Is there a way to push this Widget "on top" of the stack and kind of ignore the context or do I just have to hide the bar in this case? How would you do that?

Thanks

Comment: You want to push (Navigator.push) from FeedScreen to another widget?

Comment: Yes, but currently I am getting the NavigationBar on this other widget because of the Stack. I want to avoid the NavigationBar on only this new widget that I am pushing.

Comment: By `NavigationBar`, you mean Android Navigation Bar ?

Comment: No, I mean the BottomNavigationBar

Comment: Post `FeedScreen` content

Comment: check new answer

Comment: Remove the answer and edit the original post

Comment: So you need to hide the bottomNavigationBar in FeedScreen ?

Comment: No, I want to push a VideoPlayer from this FeedScreen, when a user taps on one of the stories in `StoriesListView()` and i need to hide the NavBar on this VideoPlayer

Comment: bottomNavigationBar is hidden by default when you push to a new Page

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the BottomNavigationBar isn't even on the page because of the OffStage and the Stack. It comes from the parent widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap you `Scaffold` with a `Navigator` and use `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => Foo()));` to push the `Foo` widget on top of everything.